# select2 deja de funcionar en un modal múltiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, select2

hola tengo un problema con select2, tengo un proyecto en laravel donde tengo una tabla donde enumero los datos a mostrar y en las ultimas casillas de mi tabla en todos los datos uso un botón que abre un modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para diferenciar el modal usa un nombre más un guion y el id de los datos:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"  data-toggle="modal" data- 
  target="#examplemodal-{{$user->id}}">
    <i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i>
 </button> 
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="examplemodal-{{$user->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body"> 
            <div class="card card-body">
                {!! Form::open(['url' => '/date','files'=>'true']) !!}
                    {{Form::token()}} 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-4" id="select"> 
                            <label for="name">Users:</label><br>
                            <select name="entidad_id" class="form-control selectAdmwn" style="width:100%"> 
                                    <option value="{{$user->user_id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>  
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::submit('Guardar',['class' =>'btn btn-primary btn-lg']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

pero en ese modal uso select2 para tener un acceso rápido a los datos de una selección, pero como la identificación de mi modal ya tiene esa estructura que se muestra en el código de arriba, select2 deja de funcionar.

he visto que usan este código para resolver pero en ese caso usan un id único para un modal en mi caso uso varios modales como podría hacerlo?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tecnics').select2({
dropdownParent: 'modal-id'
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

no veo el componente con el id **tecnics**, pero en todo caso si tu select2 esta en un modal debes llamarlo cuando el modal este visible.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
  // tu llamada aqui...
   $('#tecnics').select2({
     dropdownParent: 'modal-id'
   });
})
```

de otra forma no funcionará

Answer (score 0):

Puede que no me haya explicado bien, pero agradezco su ayuda, llegué a la solución agregando un **onClick** el botón modal para pasar su identificación en una función de JavaScript.

```
<button type="button" onClick='mandarId({{$user->id}})' class="btn btn- 
 outline-success" title="Crear orden de compra" data-toggle="modal" data- 
 target="#TareAddModalOrdenAdm-{{$user->id}}">
   <i class="fas fa-folder-plus"></i>
</button>
```

y en mi script el id obtenida la paso a una variable y luego llamo al select2 donde en el dropdownParent hago una combinación y pongo mi variable creada

```
<script>
function mandarId(id){
var id_modal = id;
$('.selectAdmin').select2({
  width: '100%',
  dropdownParent: $('#select-'+id_modal )
 });
}
```

cabe señalar que para que esto funcione antes de que nuestra selección debe tener una identificación principal donde pasamos la identificación.

```
<div class="form-group col-4" id="select-{{$user->id}}"> 
 <label for="name">User:</label><br>
 <select name="entidad_id" class="form-control selectAdmin" 
  style="width:100%">
      <option value=""></option>
 </select>
</div>
```

de esa manera logré que select2 funcionara en todos mis modales. espero que sirva de ayuda a los que tienen el mismo inconveniente que yo